# How to convert a data frame of Dates and Frequency to a quarterly basis? R

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

I have a data of from 2016-2019
Here is a sample of my data

```
print(myData)
      Date      Freq
    2016-08-08  14
    2016-08-09  20  
    2016-08-10  34  
    2016-08-11  32
    2016-08-12  19
    2016-08-15  35
    2016-08-16  32
```

I want to create a line plot but I would like to see something like this that way I can see the trend on a quarterly basis.

```
  Date   Freq
2016 Q1   300
2016 Q2   313
2016 Q3   313
2016 Q4   432
2017 Q1   313
2017 Q2   131
```

How can I do this in R?

Comment: Are the expected quarters based on the input showed

Answer (score 2):

We can use `as.yearqtr` from `zoo`

```
library(zoo)
myData %>%
    mutate(Date = as.yearqtr(Date))
```

If the column is not already a `Date` class, convert to `Date` class first

```
myData <- myData %>%
              mutate(Date = as.yearqtr(as.Date(Date)))
```

Answer (score 0):

`lubridate` has a function `quarter`:

```
quarter(myData$Date)
```

so for your data you can simply write:

```
myData <- myData %>% mutate(quarter = quarter(Date)
```